# Servlet doesn't init

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I used  servlets in my project. Everything was fine util today. I use GWT, but I don't think it matters. On my server side I need to get the context path like that

```
path = ConfAppServer.getRealContextPath() + "/docviewer";
logger.debug("Path = " + path);
```

But in the log file I get the following

```
Path = null/docviewer
```

`ConfAppServer` class contains the server-side configuration. Some settings are set when you run the servlet `ConfigServlet`.

```
public class ConfAppServer {
    private static String   realContextPath;
    public static String getContextPath() {
        return contextPath;
    }

    public static String getRealContextPath() {
        return realContextPath;
    }
}

public class ConfAppServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    LOG.info("begin ConfAppServlet init");
}
```

But I don't get the last log info. Servlet doesn't init.
Here is my `web.xml` file

```
<servlet>
  <description>Servlet to identify and download the application settings</description>
  <servlet-name>ConfAppServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.myproject.servlet.ConfAppServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

But when I run my project in Eclipse, servlet works fine. But when I deploy war on the server, the servlet stops working.

I use Eclipse Indigo with default inner server. And my outer server is Apache Tomcat 7

Help me please solve my issue. What should I do? Why this servlet doesn't init and how to fix it?

**Edit**
In my tomcat log file I found this line

```
ERROR:  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\null\docviewer
```

**Edit 2**
I found the error in my log files

```
Dec 03, 2014 10:14:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet ConfAppServlet as unavailable
Dec 03, 2014 10:14:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /egr threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: by.avest.crypto.pkcs11.provider.AvestProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1043)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5279)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Edit 3**
I added the missing class to the lib folder and everything works fine. It is quite strange because I don't change anything connected to this class. Thank you all for your posts!

Comment: Have you checked your Tomcat logs? There should be something on `catalina.out` which helps you determine the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try calling `super.init(config)` in init method.